# MySQL: Get the ID of the preceding record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
ID  NAME    ...n
1   JANE
2   SAM
3   PENNY
4   WATSON
5   ALISON
6   HANNA
7   BRIAN
..  ..
.   .
```

This table is not ordered alphabetically. I want to make such a selection that:

1) The table gets alphabetically ordered A..Z (ORDER BY NAME)

2) I want to supply the ID (or NAME) and get the ID (or NAME) of the preceding row.
e.g. -> Once alphabetically ordered. I want to supply BRIAN (7) and get ALISON (5)

I am using PHP and MySQL.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Fetch the result of the query into an array, loop the array and if preceding array key exists - it's your preceding record.

Comment: Do you have code examples where you have tried to achieve the solution yourself?

Comment: Can you have duplicate names?, if so, how wold you choose who is the preceding one?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM names
WHERE name < 'BRIAN'
ORDER BY name DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select ID, name from
(select *
 from myTable
 where name < ?
 order by name desc) sq
group by ()
```

Comment: This is using MySQL-specific behaviour, isn't it?  I mean, to only get the one row, does the `GROUP BY` only return the 'top' (because of the inner `ORDER BY`) row?

Comment: Out of curiosity (except that the example doesn't work due to unquoted reserved words), why would you perform this purely in MySQL? It's unnecessary duplication of records, no matter the syntax used to obtain such a record.

Comment: @N.B.: What unnecessary duplication of records?

Comment: If you want to force current record to display info about the one before (which is already in the list), that's duplication of the data, is it not?

Comment: @N.B.: No. The OP asked "I want to supply the ID (or NAME) and get the ID (or NAME) of the preceding row". The query receives a single (name) value as an input, and returns a name and corresponding ID as output - there is no duplication.

Comment: N.B. This is good coding. Involving PHP, arrays and loops is bad coding. Thank you Mark Bannister, thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarkBannister, shall I place two apostrophes in between the parentheses of group by () statement? Because if it's left empty, it naturally gives an error.

Comment: @Phil: I don't have an instance of MySQL to hand - in most SQLs that I know, group by () is acceptable; I thought MySQL was the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table where id < (select id where condition order by condition) 
order by condition limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Populate the `@given_id` with the required id and make sure you have an index on NAME:

```
SELECT @target_id as prev_id
FROM names, (SELECT @prev_id:=-1, @target_id:=-1, @given_id:=7) as init
WHERE IF(ID=@given_id,
         GREATEST(@target_id:=@prev_id, @prev_id:=ID),
         LEAST(0, @prev_id:=ID))
ORDER BY NAME;
```

If you need to fetch other fields beside id, put the query in a subquery and make a join with the table on prev_id = id.